# WSO2 Business Process Server 3.2.0 getTaskDetails

Tags: wso2

Is there any way to get human task details in Business Process Server 3.2.0 through webservice? I tried to call operation getTaskDetails in HumanTaskClientAPIAdmin, but server response is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>This operation is not currently supported in this version of WSO2 BPS.</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is this operation implemented and available? Or is there any other way to get task details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently getTaskDetails() is not supported, and will be available with BPS 3.5.0. But same functionality is provided by loadTask() operation. loadTask provides additional taskdetails which is not provided by getTaskDetails().